Has the inceptor (control stick) ever been controlled via using CAN bus control?
The CAN bus is being used widely in the automotive industry, and some aircraft are using the CAN bus control.
Is there any inceptor (control stick) or throttle that can be connected to the CAN?

Might be worth clarifying - is this trying to find one for use in CAN based simulator project (so does not actually need to be from an aircraft) or looking for in use aircraft that CAN bus the controls?

@GremlinWranger Thanks for the comment. Yes! It is actually for the usage of simulator project. I'm looking for both inceptor and the throttle which are running based on CAN bus.

not my domain but suggest looking for industrial equipment controllers rather than aviation for your sim project. They will be cheaper than aviation and more robust than consumer USB devices.
